# JavaScript Closures: Add the numbers of an array by calling the inner function

Tags: javascript, closures

I have an array with random numbers. I want to add the sum of these numbers by using calling the inner function using the outer function. Basically, using closures.

```js
let arr = [93, 95, 88, 0, 55, 91];

let addMany = function(arr){
    let addTwo = function (numbers) {
        console.log('array', arr)
        console.log('numbers', numbers)

        return numbers.reduce((acc,cur) => acc+cur,0)
    }
    return addTwo(arr);
}
let sum = new addMany(arr);
console.log('final sum', sum)

let res = sum.addTwo();

console.log(res);
```

I also think I am passing array 'arr' bit too many times. I could be wrong.

I have already tried it using IIFE and modular approach. That one worked fine. I am trying to achieve the same this way.

Comment: outer/inner/new/iife? quite unclear, what you want. maybe it would help if you add the array and the call of it and the result.

Comment: I don't see any good reason to use closures here. Anything you add around the `addTwo` function looks artificial. It's a function, it can be called with an array argument, that's it. Keep it simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `return addTwo(arr)` you are already returning the result directly. I assume you rather want to return `addTwo` itself, and use `arr` inside `addTwo`:

```
let addMany = function(arr){
  let addTwo = function () {
    console.log('array', arr)
    return arr.reduce((acc,cur) => acc+cur,0)
  };
  return addTwo;
}
```

The  you'd call it as:

```
 const closured = addMany(1, 2, 3);
 console.log(closured()); // call addTwo
```

---

In your example you are calling it as `(new addMany(...)).addTwo()` ... to achieve that behaviour, remove the `return` as constructors do not return anything, amd assign `addTwo` as a method to `this` (which is the returned object):

```
let addMany = function(arr){
  this.addTwo = function () {
    console.log('array', arr);

    return arr.reduce((acc,cur) => acc+cur,0)
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could take a instanciable function and a prototype for adding the values.

```js
function Numbers(array) {
    this.numbers = array;
}

Numbers.prototype.add = function () {
    return this.numbers.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);
};

var array = [93, 95, 88, 0, 55, 91],
    numbers = new Numbers(array),
    result = numbers.add();

console.log(result);
```

An other possibillity is to use a fluent interface, where you return an object with some functions, where you can chain the functions.

```js
function take(array) {
    var object = {
            add: () => array.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0),
            update: cb => take(array.map(cb)),
            valueOf: () => array
        };
    return object;
}

var array = [93, 95, 88, 0, 55, 91],
    numbers = take(array),
    result = numbers.add();

console.log(result);
console.log(numbers.valueOf());
console.log(numbers.update(x => 2 * x).valueOf());
```